# Array with Foreach not Working as Answer Key

Tags: php, arrays

This is the code I'm using to calculate and display quiz scores...

```
$answer1 = $_POST['q1'];
$answer2 = $_POST['q2'];
$answer3 = $_POST['q3'];
$answer4 = $_POST['q4'];
$answer5 = $_POST['q5'];
$answer6 = $_POST['q6'];
$answer7 = $_POST['q7'];
$answer8 = $_POST['q8'];
$answer9 = $_POST['q9'];
$answer10 = $_POST['q10'];

$totalCorrect = 0;

if ($answer1 == "A") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer2 == "Jupiter") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer3 == "C") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer4 == "D") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer5 == "A") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer6 == "C") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer7 == "C") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer8 == "C") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer9 == "B") { $totalCorrect++; }
if ($answer10) { $totalCorrect++; }
```

It works, but it's a little amateurish. I'm eventually going to have dozens of quizzes, so I'd like to start streamlining things as much as possible.

This array looks a lot cooler - but it isn't working. If I get all 10 questions right, it displays a $totalCorrect value of 0 (as dictated by the first line of code). If I comment that line out - // $totalCorrect = 0; - then it displays nothing at all.

```
$totalCorrect = 0;
$answers = [1 => 'A', 2 => 'Jupiter', 3 => 'C', 4 => 'D', 5 => 'A', 6 => 'C', 7 => 'C', 8 => 'B', 9 => 'B', 10 => 'AA', 11 => 'A'];
foreach ($answers as $num => $answer)
{
 $key = 'answer-'.$num;
 if (isset($_POST[$key]) && $_POST[$key] === $answer)
 {
    $totalCorrect++;
 }
}
```

Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$key = 'answer-'.$num;
```

change to

```
$key = 'q'.$num;
```

To make more understandable, can try this as well

```
$totalCorrect = 0;
$answers = [1 => 'A', 2 => 'Jupiter', 3 => 'C', 4 => 'D', 5 => 'A', 6 => 'C', 7 => 'C', 8 => 'B', 9 => 'B', 10 => 'AA', 11 => 'A'];
foreach ($answers as $num => $answer)
{
  $question = 'q'.$num;
  if (isset($_POST[$question]) && $_POST[$question] === $answer)
  {
    $totalCorrect++;
  }
}
$pct = round( (($totalCorrect/count($answers)) * 100), 0);
echo $totalCorrect.' correct for '.$pct.'%';
```

Comment: The % function isn't working; it displays "4 correct for 0%." However, it fixed my original problem. ;)

Comment: Awesome; displaying the percentage was going to be my next project, so you answered two questions at once. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have `q[n]` not `answer-[n]` keys in the `$_POST` array. Just use the following :

```
foreach ($answers as $num => $answer)
    if (isset($_POST['q' . $num]) && $_POST['q' . $num] === $answer)
        $totalCorrect++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misassigning `$key` for your purposes.

In your first (working example) the keys are `'q1'`, `'q2'`, etc. 
In your second example, you keys are `'answer-1'`, `'answer-2'`, etc.

```
$totalCorrect = 0;
$answers = [1 => 'A', 2 => 'Jupiter', 3 => 'C', 4 => 'D', 5 => 'A', 6 => 'C', 7 => 'C', 8 => 'B', 9 => 'B', 10 => 'AA', 11 => 'A'];
foreach ($answers as $num => $answer) {
  $key = 'q' . $num;  //fixed code here
  if (isset($_POST[$key]) && $_POST[$key] === $answer) {
    $totalCorrect++;
  }
}
```